# Android disabling a button

Tags: android

I can't figure out why this wouldn't set a button to be disabled?

```
btnSaturdayStartTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSaturdayStartTime);
btnSaturdayStartTime.setEnabled(false);
```

When I click on the button it still fires the listener.

Comment: Are you sure you got the right id for your button? That should work in reality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using btnSaturdayStartTime.setClickable(false).

See [setClickable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable%28boolean%29) from the docs.

Answer (score 2):

try the method : `Button.setClickable(false) ;` 
or delete the listener on your button  like this : `button.setOnClickListener(null);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the button is recreated or re-enabled between you disabling it an the user click interaction.
Are you sure you are disabling the right button?
What version of Android are you targeting?